# Is there a better way to handle inputs in this case to solve OverflowError: int too large to convert to float?

Tags: python, factorial

I'm writing code to solve a basic factorial equation, however when the code is getting tested, I have no control over the inputs (I don't actually know the inputs). I'm passing some of the test cases but for others I'm getting an Overflow Error stating that the int is too large to convert to float. The result needs to be truncated to 6 decimal places too. the error is occurring on the second last line every time.

```
import math

def fact(n):
    return math.factorial(n)

def going(n):
    first = 1/fact(n)
    second = 0

    for i in range(n):
        second += fact(i + 1)
    
    result = first * second

    return float("{:.6f}".format(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use floating point for the intermediate value. Instead of calculating `1/fact(n)` at the beginning, divide by `fact(n)` at the end.

And instead of formatting to get 6 decimal places, use the `round()` function.

```
def going(n):
    second = sum(fact(i) for i in range(1, n+1))
    result = second / fact(n)

    return round(result, 6)
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved the error, as for why I'm formatting the result, i need to to stop returning the decimals after 6, rather than rounding. so for example something like 1.2345678 needs to be returned as 1.234567 rather than 1.234568, but my formatting returns it rounded anyways

Comment: `:.6f` also rounds, it doesn't truncate. If you want to do that, you should process it as a string, not with numeric methods.